# Перевод переменных хранящих строчные значения в числовые

Tags: bash

Есть переменные, которые хранят 2-е последние строки некоторого файла:

```
a=`tail -n 2 1.txt | head -n 1`

b=`tail -n 2 1.txt | tail -n 1`
```

Заранее известно, что в этих строках содержатся числа. Как перевести эти переменные в числа?

Comment: у вас две переменные с одинаковым именем?

Comment: в bash нет типов, поэтому нельзя перевести что-то в число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне показалось или этим вопросом в разных вариациях сегодня заспамлен весь ХэшКод? ;)
Не нужно ничего никуда переводить, просто используйте арифметическую подстановку или `expr`, вот пример:

```
# Записываем в a предпоследнюю строку файла 1.txt
a=$(tail -n 2 1.txt | head -n 1)

# Записываем в b последнюю строку файла 1.txt
b=$(tail -n 1 1.txt)

# Выводим на экран сумму
echo $((a + b))

# Другой вариант
echo $(expr $a + $b)
```

Чтобы сказать конкретнее, как поступить в том или ином случае нужен контекст, ваша задача.

Comment: конкретно необходимо получить числовое значение a и числовое значение b

Comment: @ivan31, в  bash у переменных нет понятия **тип**. Поэтому вопрос достаточно бессмысленный.

@northerner правильно сказал Вам про контекст, и намекнул на спам. От себя добавлю, почитайте что-нибудь по программированию в unix shell.

Comment: В BASH нет типов данных, но есть автоматическое преобразование. В частности, для переменных, объявленных  declare -i и local -i

Answer (score 0):

Объявите переменную с помощью delcare -i var (если это глобальная переменная) или с помощью local -i (если это локальная переменная функции)/

В этом случае вам сразу станут доступны чудеса наподобие:

```
declare -i n g
n+=1 # после "пустой" декларации без присваивания n было ==0, а теперь n==1
g=(n+5)*6 # g=(1+5)*6=36
echo "n=$n, g=$g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Привет.

У меня были сложности при создании JSON факта для Ansible - требовалось числовое значение объема накопителя.

задача решилась через **printf**

справка

```
%n  Assigns the number of characters printed so far to the variable named in the corresponding argument. Can't specify an array index. If the given name is already an array, the value is assigned to the zeroth element.
%a  Interprets the associated argument as double, and prints it in the form of a C99 hexadecimal floating-point literal.
```

код

```
a=$(tail -n 2 1.txt | head -n 1)
printf '"your number is:" %n' $a
```

Answer (score 0):

Цитирую [Advanced Bash-Scripting 
Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html):

> Bash does not segregate its variables by type. Essentially, *Bash 
>   variables are character strings*

Bash не знает типов переменных, это всегда только символьные строки. И далее:

> but, depending on context, Bash permits arithmetic operations and 
>   comparisons on variables. The determining factor is whether the value of 
>   a variable contains only digits.

Bash допускает арифметические операции над переменными, но решающим фактором здесь является. содержат ли они только цифры.

Вопрос должен звучать - не перевести переменные в числа, а проверить, содержат ли они числа.

Например, содержат ли переменные, полученные из 2-ух последних строк в файле, только числовые значения, а также не учитывать незначащие нули:

```
$ echo -e "text lines n\n001234\n005678" > 1.txt
$ readarray arr <<< $(tail -2 1.txt)
$ echo "$((10#${arr[0]})) $((10#${arr[1]}))"
1234 5678
```